# change background image and text, rotating banner style

Tags: jquery, fade, cycle

I want to change the background image and the content of a div every 5 seconds or so, just like a rotating banner, using jquery.

There will be a list of image url's and a list of text, each of which will fade in/out in the order they are in and continue cycling.

I have set up the doc for somebody to please guide me. 
All help greatly appreciated.
Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/samjsharples/pNTqP/

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="titles">
        <p>Title1</p>
        <p>Title2</p>
        <p>Title3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it correctly

```
var imgs = ['http://www.google.com/logos/1998/googleburn.jpg', 'http://www.google.com/logos/1998/googlebeta.jpg', 'http://www.google.com/logos/1999/googlepump.gif'],
    i = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    $('.banner').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgs[i] + ')').find('p:eq(' + i + ')').show().siblings().hide()
            .end().end().fadeIn(300, function () {
            i++;
            if (i === imgs.length) {
                i = 0
            }
        });
    });
}, 5000)
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/pNTqP/7/)

Comment: sorry, one more thing. How to I target just the background image and the P tags to fade in and out. There are other things in the div that I dont want to fade.

Comment: Change the `selector` to `.titles` and the CSS a little. The the things you don't want to fade put them in `.banner`. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/pNTqP/10/)